# Is there a way to search only in files that have been changed in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to search for a string in files that have changed?  I want to search for the comments I've added before I commit them, but I only know how to search for comments in every file of my project.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Current accepted answer is outdated, this is how you currently search only in your changed files: (don't miss that you should scroll down, the scrollbar is hidden when it's still)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Searching changed files is an option in the "Find in Path" function.

In the scope of your find, select Custom, then use the dropdown to select Changed Files.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, looks like "Custom" is called "Scope" now and you have to scroll down to see "Changed Files" (took me a bit to find it).

Answer (score 3):

As of Intellij 2022.2.4 the option is located in the "Find in Files dialog" (at least on MacOS).
[image]